# Woocommerce admin orders custom button for removing stock

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Need help updating my product stock on woocommerce admin order page. I currently have some code that works but it removes stock from the wrong product. Does anyone know why?

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_order_itemmeta', 'action_woocommerce_order_item_add_button', 10, 2);

function action_woocommerce_order_item_add_button($item_id, $item)
{
  $product = $item->get_product();
    $id = $item->get_product_id();

        echo '<button type="button" onclick="document.post.submit();" class="button generate-items" style="background: red; color: white;">' . __( 'Töm lagersaldo', 'hungred' ) . 
            '<input type="hidden" value="'.$id.'" name="renew_order_single_product" /></button>';
    
}

add_action('save_post', 'renew_save_again', 10, 3);
function renew_save_again($post_id, $post, $update){
    $slug = 'shop_order';
    if(is_admin()){
            // If this isn't a 'woocommercer order' post, don't update it.
            if ( $slug != $post->post_type ) {
                    return;
            }

            if(isset($_POST['renew_order_single_product']) && $_POST['renew_order_single_product']){
    
                //removes stock for specified product
                global $woocommerce;
                $quantity = 0;
                $product_id = $_POST['renew_order_single_product'];
                $woocmmerce_instance = new WC_Product($product_id);
                $new_quantity=wc_update_product_stock( $woocmmerce_instance, $quantity);
        
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is, that you're adding a button and input after each order item, so you have multiple hidden inputs with the same name, so it either takes the first hidden input or the last and that is what is updated, you need to change your logic, where you add only hidden input and change the hidden input value on button click then submit the post.

Comment: Thank you for answering! What do you mean by "change your login"? Do you have an example in code?

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo, I meant to save "change your code logic", I don't have any code, but as I explained, you're duplicating the same hidden input with different values. You need to create a logic where you have only 1 hidden input and with the button click, you change/add the value in it. Also, at the initial stage this hidden value should not have any value, it should be empty.